# dpkg error when installing TeX Live in Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

My Acer Chromebook C720 is running Ubuntu 14.04.
(I installed Ubuntu/ChrUbuntu using the script found at
[link](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html).)

I wanted to install "vanilla" TeX Live
rather than the version in the Ubuntu software repository.
And so I followed the instructions found in
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373)
to the question [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/7142)

Unfortunately, I ran into the following error
when installing the "fake" package
to make Ubuntu think it has installed TeX Live:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb
dpkg: regarding texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb containing texlive-local:
 texlive-base conflicts with texlive-common
  texlive-local provides texlive-common and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing texlive-local
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you already have another install on the computer?

Comment: I am working with a fresh installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have `texlive-base` installed? You need to remove it. (You might have installed it as a dependency without realising it.)

Comment: @cfr You're right! Somehow `texlive-base` was automatically installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User cfr pointed out that I may already have `texlive-base` installed.
To check whether this was indeed the case,
I listed the installed packages with the name "texlive*".

```
$ dpkg -l | grep texlive
ii  texlive-base                  2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries              2013.20130729.30972-2build3                         amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended     2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Recommended fonts
ii  texlive-generic-recommended   2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Generic recommended packages
ii  texlive-latex-base            2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
ii  texlive-latex-recommended     2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
```

I then uninstalled all the "texlive*" packages

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
```

The installation now works as expected.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-local.
(Reading database ... 166027 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-local (2014-1) ...
Setting up texlive-local (2014-1) ...
```

Comment: Don't forget to create symbolic links

Comment: @subhamsoni I don't recommend doing it.

Comment: @egreg Why don't you recommend creating symbolic links? The answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/7142 recommends creating these links using the command `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/* /opt/texbin`